# Estimating demographics from internet activity

Tags: classification, demography, social-network, internet

I'm looking for research papers on estimating demographic information (age, wealth, location, gender etc.) out of internet activities (preferably social network activity or browser history).

Where would be a good place to look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last summer, Kaggle ran a competition to predict a users psychopathy,  Machiavellianism, Narcissism etc. using only Twitter data. You can see the competition and results here:

1. [personality competition](http://www.kaggle.com/c/twitter-personality-prediction)
2. [psychopathy](http://www.kaggle.com/c/twitter-psychopathy-prediction)

I recall there was a published paper on the psychopathy prediction, here: 
http://www.onlineprivacyfoundation.org/research_/Sumner_Predicting_Dark_Triad_Traits_from_Twitter_Usage_V5.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Stuff that I found so far:
[Demographic Prediction Based on User’s Browsing 
Behavior](http://wwwconference.org/www2007/papers/paper686.pdf)
[A Machine Learning Approach to Twitter User Classification](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/ICWSM/ICWSM11/paper/download/2886/3262&ei=lr3VUO3qBuTK0AWUhICIDg&usg=AFQjCNEXdrelWFd_y-1oMIn06kRIx8spdQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k)
[Classifying Latent User Attributes in Twitter](https://csc-869-mlog.googlecode.com/files/p37-rao.pdf)